# Relationship between standard normal distribution and normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, inverse-gaussian-distribution

Assume we have $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. What is the value/formula of
$$\Phi^{-1}(\Phi_{\mu, \sigma}(x)),$$
for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

$\Phi^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of the standard normal distribution and $\Phi_{\mu, \sigma}$ denotes the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: The inner term $\Phi_{\mu,\sigma}(x)$ gives you the rank of $x$ given mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, call it $r \in [0,1]$. The outer function $\Phi^{-1}(r)$ gives you the $r^{th}$ quantile of a standard normal. Overall, the formula gives you a quantile of the standard normal with the same "relative rank" as $x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between normal distribution and standard normal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/what-is-the-difference-between-normal-distribution-and-standard-normal-distribut)

Comment: Using the cdf transform turns $X$ into a Uniform $(0,1)$ variate $U$. Using then the inverse standard cdf turns $U$ into a standard normal variate. In the Normal case, since this is a location-scale family a closed form representation is easily derived.